# Images are not showing while you're not logged in on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a Wordpress website with the following plugins:

- Contact Form 7
- Easy Photo Album
- Memphis Documents Library
- New User Approve
- Really Simple SSL
- SSL Insecure Content Fixer
- User Menus
- User Rol Editor
- User Specific Content

A while ago I activated SSL on the domain. Since that moment I have had some problems with the images. I uninstalled every single plugin to see which plugin might have a negative effect on the images. But I cannot find the problem.

When I am logged in I can open the direct path to the image. When I am not logged in the site redirect me to the home page.

Does anyone have an idea what I can try to solve this problem?

Comment: Try flashing you urls, go to permalinks settings and hit save save

Comment: Unfortunately, flashing the urls didn't work for me

Comment: Mostly issues where it works when logged in, and not when logged in , are related to caching. Make sure you clear cache any caching plugin or server level cache by your hosting.

Comment: I have tried tried several things but I have still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that the folder 'wp-content' had its own .htaccess-file. That file had this content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ http://example.com/ [NC]
```

I changed http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ https://example.com/ [NC]
```

This solved the problem.